# Using initialized variable after placement new from the constructor tripping UB?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, placement-new

Disregarding whether the following can be achieved through other, more safe constructs - I'm simply interested in whether or not the following results in a well-defined output.

Assume you have a struct A:

```
struct A {
    Foo* foo;    
}
```

And a struct B inheriting from it:

```
struct B : A {
    B() {
        foo->some_function(); // UB
    }
}
```

Sure enough if you were creating a `B` instance the normal way you'd trip UB, however...

```
template<typename R> 
R make_A() { // This acts like a constructor for As
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, R>::value, "R must derive from A");
    char r[sizeof(R)];
    ((R*)r)->foo = returns_some_valid_foo();
    new (r) R;

    return *((R*)r);
}

B b1; // Blows up (Could you somehow prevent this from compiling without changing B?)
B b2 = make_A<B>(); // Works fine?
```

Sheepishly assuming that C++ works like C somewhere under the hood, I'm guessing that this would be similar to having a struct instance in C, initializing it by hand, and then calling some method (in this case B's constructor) on the finished product.

Again, I'm not interested in whether you *should* do this or not, it's just a technical question.

EDIT:

If you wonder what this could be useful for, I could use it to pull out values into a plain struct from, say, a configuration file in a really terse manner. Yes it does use macros but call it a stub until C++ gets compile time reflection:

```
#define config_key($x, $def) $x = foo->get<decltype($x)>(#$x, ($def))   

struct Record : A {
    int    config_key(a, 3); // Second parameter is default value
    string config_key(b, "something");
}

auto record = make_A<Record>();
```

(Using A and foo here to stay consistent with what I wrote above, make_A is actually part of a class that does config)

Comment: `foo->some_function();` doesn't dereference a null pointer, but an uninitialized pointer containing random garbage. Either way, it's UB. `((R*)r)->foo` is UB in its own right - accessing an object before its lifetime has started. "Seems to work fine" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: I haven't even tested if this works at all. Afaik this is legal in C because it just doesn't have constructors... Is there some way to ehrm, force it to do this?

Comment: What's the goal of the exercise? Why exactly do you want to a) leave a member uninitialized, but b) nevertheless use it in constructor? What actual problem you are trying to solve, that you believe would be helped by such a bizarre approach?

Comment: so you wrote it. maybe the UB sanitizer from clang has something to say about it

Comment: I'll edit the question to show it, I mean... I could just store the reference to Foo somewhere else and make B pick it up from there but that doesn't sound rock solid at all. (thread safety...)

Comment: There is an another case of the UB here: `char r[]` is not aligned properly.

Comment: I read about that when looking up placement new, but I don't know how I actually do align it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
((R*)r)->foo = returns_some_valid_foo();
```

is undefined behavior. There is no object of type `R` at `r`. Full stop. If you flip the two lines so that you create the `R` first, then you're fine (modulo `r` being insufficiently aligned).

Or really, just:

```
R r;
r.foo = returns_some_valid_foo();
return r;
```

Comment: ... which would call the constructor too early for me, yea. But reading the standard it really is UD (section [basic.life], 5.2 `the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the
object`)  Its not obvious to me why, but there's nothing I can do about it.

Comment: OP is trying to get `foo`'s value set before the ctor call begins and use that value in the ctor. That's simply impossible and flipping the lines won't help.

Comment: @T.C Misunderstood the question I guess.

Comment: Looks like the only real alternative (provided I want to keep the syntax) is to use some sort of global variable and supply the reference that way. Really unfortunate.

Comment: @Vic: The constructor of `A` is complete before the constructor of `B` and it is the place to construct / initialize parts of `A` before the constructor of `B` runs.